# Space vs the space

Tags: capitalization, definite-articles

Talking about the(?) space as somewhat out of the Earth's atmosphere, should one

1. Use article "the"?
2. write Space or space?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [*Humans began the physical exploration **of space** during the 20th century with the advent of high-altitude balloon flights, followed by manned rocket launches*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Space has multiple meanings. One is the enormous dark near-vaccuum which exists outside our world, and this is never used with the definite article "the" or the indefinite article "a".  It's used like a proper noun place name, except not capitalised, so you would say *"I'm going to space"* or *"Space is very big"* in the same way you would say *"I'm going to London"* or *"New York is very big."*.

An exception is when "space" is used as the first part of a noun phrase - *"The space ship was quite impressive."* or *"A space probe was launched on wednesday"*.  Here, "space" becomes an adjective, and again it's following the "place name" rules, like saying "The New York Mets" or "The London fog".

Another meaning of "space" is like a *gap* or a *void*, and you can use "a" or "the" with this, like

*"There's a space in the middle of the page to write your name"* or *"The space between songs is too big on this album".*

Answer (score 5):

No need to use *the* or capitalize the *s*. You can use [outer space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) to be more specific.